# Response BinaryWrite not working on Android browser

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

I have a byte array in the database and i need to show that in a pdf file format. Here is the way i did that. However, this doesn't work on Android tablets(checked in 2.3.5 and 3.2).

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", binaryData.Length.ToString());
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=ClientDocument.PDF");
// Response.BinaryWrite(binaryData);
Response.OutputStream.Write(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);
Response.End();
```

Can you guys think of any way i could make it work on all the browsers?

Appreciate the help

Thanks

Comment: what error did you get ? maybe you do not have installed the adobe pdf reader ? also why .PDF is not lower case ?

Comment: i am not getting any error. It just keeps on loading. I am just trying diff ways to make it work. Hence i changed the pdf to PDF. Both ways didn't work.

Comment: It is working on all the browsers (IE,FF,Chrome) on PC. It works on ipad too, but not on Android tablets.

Comment: Another thing i noticed is, in Chrome(PC), it is being downloaded as an attachment. In IE, it just opens in a window, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things...

1. Change the content type to correct mime-type of PDF files.  There are vast array of these in use application/pdf, application/x-pdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf", we just use application/pdf.

   Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
2. Then if you want the browser to open and display the PDF file, remove the Content-Disposition header.
3. ... or ... if you want the browser to download the PDF file change the Content-Disposition type to "attachment" rather than "inline".

   Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=ClientDocument.PDF");

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have " Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";" because i wanted to display all the files in pdf format. The user can upload any format like .jpg,.png,.pdf etc. But i wanted to show them in pdf. If i have the pdf in place of octet-stream and when the user tries to open .jpg, then it is throwing error. So, i changed it to octet-stream and it is opening all the files.

Comment: Now I'm confused, you can't display a jpg as if it were a PDF, you need to create a PDF and put the jpg in it.  Reguardless, the mime-type controls how the browser interprets the data and it needs to be correct based on the content of the document that was uploaded.  Most desktop browsers will attempt to 'discover' the content type when it is not provided or set to application/binary or application/octet-stream and this is why it sorta-works.

Comment: Is there any way that i could make it work for all the formats and in all the browsers?

Comment: How do i create a pdf and put jpg in it? Is it something like this? Just give the Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; and binarywrite the jpg byte array.

Comment: The best way is to use the correct content-type header based on the file extension they uploaded.  This will not however view a jpg as a PDF.  To do that you need special code for each and every file type to convert it into a PDF.

Comment: Is that process of converting each file type to pdf takes large amount of code or something that could be done easily?

Comment: I tried above 2 things what you told and it is still not working on android tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded to latest version of Android on the test tablets/phones?

That fixed it for me when I had a similar problem (PDFs not opening or downloading when sent to browser from stream or byte[] on Android only).